# Extract everything before negative index in string

Tags: javascript, node.js

Two examples of length measurements:

- "180cm"
- "70in"

I want to extract both the number, and the unit. I know the unit is either 'cm' or 'in' so I can assume the unit character length to always be **2**. The number before however, can be any number of any character length.

I have looked att various JS string methods like slice, substr, split and so on. I achieved to extract the last part by using `.slice(-2)` which gives me either 'cm' or 'in'.

But how can I extract the first part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a start index:

```js
"180cm".slice(0, -2) // "180"
```

Comment: Wow... can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks!

Comment: You can prefix `+` to convert string to number in case you need. Like this: `const num = +"180cm".slice(0, -2)`

Comment: Do you happen to know if it's possible to separate and extract both at once?
Like
const [val, unit] = ...something.slice

Comment: Sadly, Javascript does not have a builtin way to split a string at an index. There is a way with regex though: `const [val, unit] = "180cm".match(/^(\d+)(cm|in)$/).slice(1);`

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```js
var str = "1234in";
var res = str.substring(0,str.length-2);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
function getData(data) {
   var number = data.slice(0, -2);
   var unit = data.slice(data.length-2);
   return [number, unit]
}
```

`getData("155cm") will return  ["155", "cm"]`

`getData("1554241in") will return ["1554241", "in"]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general solution using regular expression and named groups:

```
const VALUE_GROUP_NAME = 'value';
const UNIT_GROUP_NAME = 'unit';

const UNITS = ['cm', 'in'];

const regExp = new RegExp(`^(?<${VALUE_GROUP_NAME}>[0-9.]+)(?<${UNIT_GROUP_NAME}>${UNITS.join('|')})$`);

const result = '10cm'.match(regExp).groups;

console.log(result[VALUE_GROUP_NAME]); // or simply result.value
console.log(result[UNIT_GROUP_NAME]); // or simply result.unit
```

The benefit here is it will match only strings that contain that pattern and recognize only specific units of measurement which you predefine in an array thus shielding you from unexpected errors. If you need to catch all possible "units" or arbitrary strings(with arbitrary length) after the numeric value, you can change the regular expression to something like:

```
const regExp = new RegExp(`^(?<${VALUE_GROUP_NAME}>[0-9.]+)(?<${UNIT_GROUP_NAME}>[A-z]+$`);
```

This is a solution which is easily extensible and don't require refactoring to handle new cases contrary to simply using `substring` with static length which is not a solution at all the moment you introduce a third unit with different length.